# Static variable initialization inside a function in C

Tags: c, variables, static

Consider the following function

```
int16_t read_input(void)
{
   static int32_t previous_input = read_encoder(); // <--Not a compile time constant

   //Read current_input 

   if (previous_input - current_input > SOME_THRESHLD)
       some_action();

   previous_input = current_input;

   //some more code + return statement

}
```

Since the variable is not initialised to a compile time constant I an not able to declare it without errors.There are 2 reasons why I want to keep the variable as static variable inside the function

1) The variable is not getting used anywhere else in the program. So there is no need of keeping it as a global variable

2) The previous function needs to be initialised to current input or else  during the initial run the difference between current input and previous input can go very high because of the encoder connected to current input (and there is no way of telling where could be the encoder value which depends on how much the user has rotated it before turning it off). This will create false triggering of other functions.

Is there any way of declaring a static variable inside a function and initializing it to value similar to example given above?

Note : This problem is a part of a complex  program and I have simplified it to avoid complexity. If there is any ambiguity in the question please let me know

Comment: I'm unclear why being static is important here.

Comment: In addition to Craig's fine answer, you can also initialize `previous_input` to a value that `read_encoder` never returns. For example, if `read_encoder` returns a number between 0 and 1023, then initializing `previous_input` to -1 allows the code to detect that there was no previous input.

Comment: @DaveNewton:- The only location where I use previous_input is inside the read_input function and it needs to preserve the value between function calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* if you're careful with an extra variable:

```
int16_t
read_input(void)
{
    static int32_t previous_input = 0;
    static int first_time = 1;

    if (first_time) {
        first_time = 0;
        previous_input = read_encoder();
    }

    // Read current_input

    if (previous_input - current_input > SOME_THRESHLD)
        some_action();

    previous_input = current_input;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

*If* `current_input` comes from `read_encoder`, here's a cleaned up version that prevents a double read on the first time.

Also, originally, I used an extra flag variable, which is necessary if there are *no* out of bounds values. But, I've included a second version that is *slightly* faster [if less safe] that uses the single variable:

```
int16_t
read_input(void)
{
    static int32_t previous_input = 0;
    static int first_time = 0;
    int32_t current_input;

    // Read current_input
    current_input = read_encoder();

    if (first_time) {
        first_time = 0;
        previous_input = current_input;
    }

    if (previous_input - current_input > SOME_THRESHLD)
        some_action();

    previous_input = current_input;
}

#define OUT_OF_BOUNDS   -1

int16_t
read_input2(void)
{
    static int32_t previous_input = OUT_OF_BOUNDS;
    int32_t current_input;

    // Read current_input
    current_input = read_encoder();

    if (previous_input == OUT_OF_BOUNDS)
        previous_input = current_input;

    if (previous_input - current_input > SOME_THRESHLD)
        some_action();

    previous_input = current_input;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can initially set the value to some default value and on first calling the method, check if the value has been initialised or not. If not then initialise it.

```
int16_t read_input(void)
{
   static int32_t previous_input = 0; // or a value indicating 'not initialised'
   if (previous_input == 0) previous_input = read_encoder();

   //Read current_input 

   if (previous_input - current_input > SOME_THRESHLD)
       some_action();

   previous_input - current_input;
}
```

Comment: Keeping the previous_input to a value indicating 'not initialized' will solve my problem. But I have one more question which is not important at this point - What if the previous_input stores a value which is -SOME_LIMIT to +SOME_LIMIT. for instance, it is attached to a continuous rotation rotary encoder. In this case, the SOME_LIMIT value is determined by the datatype storing the value and it overflows only when the datatype limit is exceeded.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way of declaring a static variable inside a function and initializing it to value similar to example given above?

I see another concern and offer an idea the solves both.

**Overflow in the subtraction**

```
if (previous_input - current_input > SOME_THRESHLD)  // OF possible
```

Given `previous_input, current_input` could independently be any of 2<sup>32</sup>, the difference has about 2<sup>33</sup> different results.  With `int` as 32-bit, code can overflow (UB) and cannot distinguish that uniquely. On exceptional platforms with 64-bit `int`, the difference is well calculated, yet now functionality differs from 32-bit platforms.

Consider using `int64_t` since 33+ bit math is needed.

```
#define SPECIAL_BIG (INT64_MAX/2)
static int64_t previous_input = SPECIAL_BIG;
if (previous_input == SPECIAL_BIG) {
   previous_input = read_encoder();  // first time
}
...
if (previous_input - current_input > SOME_THRESHLD) {
    some_action();
  }
}
...
if (previous_input - current_input > SOME_THRESHLD)  // OF not possible
```

---

On the other hand, if not all 2<sup>32</sup> combinations possible and  the subtraction and compare well fit in 32-bit math, then use a reserved value. [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) and simple detect that to perform initialization.

```
static int32_t previous_input = SPECIAL.
if (previous_input == SPECIAL) {
  previous_input = read_encoder();  // first time
}
```

---

I like the idea of a `static`  separate flag as suggested by others.  But wanted to offer another approach.

IAC, code, in general, needs OF protection with `previous_input - current_input`

Comment: You might want to add that the reason for the possible overflow is that these are signed integers.

Comment: @GermanNerd I agree mostly.  Yet the possibility of _mathematical_ overflow applies if the type is signed or unsigned integer.   Of course with unsigned the OF does not beget UB, yet it is mathematical the incorrectly answer with `previous_input - current_input > SOME_THRESHLD`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I just thought that possibly the OP will have trouble grasping why these overflows occur, and what the consequences are. I guess not everyone easily understands why INT32_MIN - INT32_MAX requires, as you say, 33-bit math.